# Problems in using ubuntu terminal after python upgrade

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, importerror, ubuntu-20.04

When I try to run the command gnome-tweaks to get my genome tweaks started, I am getting this error.

This question has been asked previously but none of those seem to work in my case, on Ubunu 20.24 after an upgrade from python 3.8 to 3.9.

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_gi' from partially initialized module 'gi' (most likely due to a circular import) (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to update the version of your preinstalled (python3.8), as there're many configurations that're based on the preinstalled version....

Comment: Definitely true--although it's worth noting in the answer that when installing a package it's probably installing the new version (e.g. python3.9) alongside the distribution version (e.g. python3.8) and not replacing it